# How to show users search phrase in SEO Title

Tags: get-the-title

How to create dynamic SEO titles?

If users search phrase should be shown in the SEO Title in the google search.

Ex: If a user searches "Meat delivery in Hyderabad" title in google search should be as "Meat delivery in Hyderabad".

However, whenever the user types the location it will replace the word Hyderabad from the above title. How to optimize the title for dynamic word phrase.

Comment: Assuming you want your page to interact with google search, I don't think that's possible. The "current" best practice is to either have a "meat delivery" page that lists your locations or have `n` amount of pages with "meat delivery $location" as the title.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick revert. Is $location replace instantly with location?

Comment: No, you need to create a page called "meat delivery place-a" and another called "meat delivery place-b" etc. You can't interact with the google search in a dynamic way like this. At least not without underhanded tricks.

Comment: Joshua's first suggestion would be best for SEO - have one meat delivery page but list all your locations. If you truly have unique content for every location then a separate meat delivery page for each location would be fine - the problem there usually is coming up with that much unique content and the chance that if the locations are close enough together they may compete with each other for ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling my comment as an answer:

Assuming you want your page to interact with the google search, I don't think that's possible, at least without "black hat" measures and potentially getting blacklisted by Google.

The "current" best practice is to either have a "meat delivery" page that lists your locations or have `n` amount of pages with "meat delivery location-a", "meat delivery location-b" as the title.

The best and easiest way would be to have a page with your general region eg "Meat delivery state" and then list the locations on that page.